# How can i update R studio

Tags: r

My R stuio version is 4.1.2
so i want to update R studio version 4.3.3

I run this code

install.packages("installr")
library(installr)
install.R()

but The r studio is not updated and only the rgui is updated.

what should i do?

install.packages("installr")
library(installr)
install.R()

Comment: The `installr` package has several functions. `install.R()` downloads the latest version of R. You want `install.RStudio()` to get the latest version of R Studio. R Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE) that makes it easier to use R, but is not the same thing as R itself.

Comment: Or just go to the RStudio website and download an installer.